# jQuery start/stop loop from 8th Iteration

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, iteration, each

I am running a similar script on two different applications, I need the statement to stop at the 8th iteration of the loop for the first script and for the second script I need it to start at the 8th iteration of the loop. Any Ideas on how to fix the code. Below shows the script pulling in all iterations of content:

```
var counter = 0;

 $.each(datasource, function(index) {
 counter++;
 // menu items
 var $menu = $menuContainer.clone();
 $menu.html('<div>' + counter + '</div> ');
 $('.menu-item-container').append($menu);
});
```

Comment: For simplicity purpose you can just write 2 different scripts for each application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I need the statement to stop at the 8th iteration of the loop for the first script*

for this you can use a *return* to stop it at the 8th iteration but you also need some identifier if the script1 is using it, like `var $script = 1;`:

```
var counter = 0;
var $script = 1; // update this number as per your call like 1 for first script 
                 // and 2 for second script.
$.each(datasource, function(index) {

    counter++;
    if($script == 2 && counter !== 8){
      continue;
    }
    // menu items
    var $menu = $menuContainer.clone();
    $menu.html('<div>' + counter + '</div> ');
    $('.menu-item-container').append($menu);

   if($script == 1 && counter <= 8){
     break;
   }
});
```

A sample code is below:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){

  if(i !== 3){
   continue;
  }
  
  console.log('use of "continue":', arr[i]);
    console.log('==========================================================');
}

for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){

  if(i === 3){
   break;
  }
  
  console.log('use of "break":', arr[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```